# How to ensure a key is stored on every Redis node in a cluster?

Tags: redis

I've been reading the [Redis cluster specification](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) (specifically the "Keys hash tags" section) and it explains how to use `{` and `}` to ensure that some key will appear on the same node in a cluster.

However, I do not see how to guarantee that a single key will appear on every node. This for values what will be used across nodes in Lua scripts as "constants" that will vary day to day (eg a currency exchange rate that is constant for a week, but will change from week to week; FWIW it's worth there are about 40 of theses constants)

---

PS- in case it actually matters the strings being uploaded into Lua are flat files of fixed length records. The record length is constant per country, but the clustering is by user so that all the users can be processed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

There is always then option of copying each "constant" per key. So when inserting a new key with a key has tag of `{Foo}` then for each constant `bar` insert `{Foo}bar`. If the constants aren't too large then the overhead should be negligible.